# How to specify relative order or priority among several Spring Boot `FailureAnalyzer`s?

Tags: spring-boot

Our project has multiple `FailureAnalyzer`s. Currently, a less informative one is kicking in before a more informative one.

Looking through the Spring Boot code, it looks like there's a way to set some sort of order but the code is fairly generic so it's difficult to see exactly how that should be done. What are the annotations to use to configure this order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analyzers [are sorted](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/ce9c053cbfc41f4753830bbb6c55ee7b2487856b/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/diagnostics/FailureAnalyzers.java#L84) using Spring Framework’s `AnnotationAwareOrderComparator`. That means that they can be ordered absolutely by annotating the class with`@Order` or by implementing `Ordered`. Relative ordering is not supported.

Comment: Is there a way to test that the "right" `FailureAnalyzer` is triggered?

Comment: To do that, I’d write a test that verifies the order of your analyzers and then trust Spring Boot to honour that order